# Oracle 11g: Sub query returning multiple rows

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, left-join

I have two tables

Table-1: **Account_Table**

```
Account_Num | Serial_Num | Transaction_Date | Balance | Frequency 
  ACC1           001           Date1            0          f1
  ACC1           002           Date2            1          f2
  ACC1           003           Date3            2          f3
```

Table-2: **Bill_Table**

```
Account_Num | Serial_Num | Version_Num | Bill_Date 
  ACC1           001            1          Date1 (say)
  ACC1           002            1          Date2
  ACC1           001            1          Date3
```

I need to get the `Bill_Date` from `Bill_Table` by joining `Account_Num` and `Serial_Num` of both `Account_Table` and `Bill_Table`.

If the Bill_Table has more than one row matches with Account_Num, Serial_Num. This is the case for `ACC1, 001 of Account_Table` matches with two rows of `ACC1, 001 of Bill_Table` then I need to get the maximum version number of the respective Account_Num, Serial_Num combination and return that row's Bill_Date.

This is a special case where the version number is same for both ACC1, 001 combination, so I need to get the `TOP 1` (that is ROWNUM = 1)

Example: Account_Table has 3 rows. Now my output should be

**Expected Result:**

```
Account_Num | Serial_Num | Bill_Date 
  ACC1           001         Date
  ACC1           002         Date
  ACC1           003         null
```

Query which I have tried is,

```
SELECT 
          A.ACCOUNT_NUM,  
          A.SERIAL_NUM, 
          B.BILL_DATE 
   FROM ACCOUNT_TABLE A, BILL_TABLE B WHERE 
         A.ACCOUNT_NUM = 'ACC1' AND 
         B.ACCOUNT_NUM = 'ACC1' AND 
         A.SERIAL_NUM = B.SERIAL_NUM AND    
         B.VERSION_NUM = (SELECT MAX (BIV.VERSION_NUM) FROM BILL_TABLE BIV
                                    WHERE BIV.ACCOUNT_NUM = 'ACC1' 
                                    AND BIV.SERIAL_NUM = B.SERIAL_NUM
                        );
```

But this query results in a table which does not show my `ACC1, 003` combination and `ACC1, 001` two times.

**OUTPUT:**

```
ACCOUNT_NUM | SERIAL_NUM | BILL_DATE 
   ACC1          001         Date
   ACC1          001         Date
   ACC2          002         Date
```

Any help will be appreciated.

P.S: One thing which I have done wrong is I am comparing only the rows that are matching both the serial numbers `A.SERIAL_NUM = B.SERIAL_NUM`. But if I remove this line then I am getting more rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do what you need, using a `LEFT JOIN` and [`ROW_NUMBER()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions137.htm) to find the correct version;

```
SELECT account_num, serial_num, version_num, bill_date
FROM (
  SELECT a.account_num,a.serial_num,b.version_num,b.bill_date,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.account_num, a.serial_num
                       ORDER BY b.version_num DESC) rn
  FROM account_table a
  LEFT JOIN bill_table b
    ON a.account_num = b.account_num
   AND a.serial_num  = b.serial_num
)
WHERE rn=1
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d3bbb/2).

Comment: +1 Awesome. pls give me some time to test with other cases. I am sure it will work.

Comment: Interesting! ROW_NUMBER() is new to me since the last time I use oracle in 2010. You have my vote, Joachim. :)

Comment: What if there are rows in the Account_Table such that they have Account_Num, Serial_Num as same but the Transaction_Date as different? According to ur query it is taking only the first one. Can u consider this one also.

Comment: @che I'm not sure what you mean, but try adding a.TransactionDate to the `PARTITION BY` clause and see if that's what you expect. If not, could you clarify by adding an example of your input/expected result to your question? (or create a new question with a more complete example, you'll get more attention from people that can answer with a new question than adding to an old one)

Comment: It is working when I write in PARTITION BY .. Thank u so much. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Two rows is happen because table Bill_table has two rows with Version_Num = 1 for Account_Num = ACC1 and serial_num = 001.

And ACC3 is not shown because you don't do LEFT OUTER JOIN yet.

Below is the query :

```
SELECT A.ACCOUNT_NUM, A.SERIAL_NUM, B.VERSION_NUM, B.BILL_DATE
FROM ACCOUNT_TABLE A
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(
    SELECT ACCOUNT_NUM, SERIAL_NUM, VERSION_NUM, BILL_DATE
    FROM (
        SELECT ACCOUNT_NUM, SERIAL_NUM, VERSION_NUM, BILL_DATE, 
        MAX(VERSION_NUM) OVER (PARTITION BY ACCOUNT_NUM, SERIAL_NUM) AS MAX_VERSION_NUM,
        MAX(BILL_DATE) OVER (PARTITION BY ACCOUNT_NUM, SERIAL_NUM, VERSION_NUM) AS MAX_BILL_DATE 
        FROM BILL_TABLE 
    ) WHERE VERSION_NUM = MAX_VERSION_NUM AND BILL_DATE = MAX_BILL_DATE
) B ON B.ACCOUNT_NUM = A.ACCOUNT_NUM AND B.SERIAL_NUM = A.SERIAL_NUM
```

Hopefully this help.

Comment: +1 Yes. I have tried using left outer join also .. but still I am not able to get the expected results